# ext js - create custom function with passed parameters

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm

Just a warning, this is my first ExtJS project.
I have two stores loaded from a webserver successfully.

1. Store containing positions
2. Store containing marketData

I've created a third store to hold all of my results.
Now I want to go through each position, find the market data record associated, and run a simple calculation.

I have done this successfully all on the event of clicking a button, but I want to separate out the function of doing the actual calculation... passing in parameters.

For now just to get the concept working I created a function called 'sayHello', but I am getting an error stating... ReferenceError: sayHello is not defined.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong to create this custom function?

Thanks!

my controller...

```
Ext.define('ExtApplication1.view.clientdetails.clientdetailsController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
alias: 'controller.clientdetails-clientdetails',

onClickCalculate: function () {
    console.log('calculation button was hit');

    var targetGrid = Ext.getCmp('positionsGridID');
    var positionsStore = targetGrid.store;

    var marketDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('marketsGridID');
    var marketDataStore = marketDataGrid.store;

    var calculatedPositionsDataGrid = Ext.getCmp('calculatedPositionsGridID');
    var calculatedPositionsDataStore = calculatedPositionsDataGrid.store;
    console.log(calculatedPositionsDataStore);

    positionsStore.each(function (record) {

        console.log('the details for the whole position');
        console.log(record);

        var bbSymbol = record.get('BBSymbol');

        var singleRecord;
        marketDataStore.each(function (record) {
            var cycleBBSymbol = record.get('BBSymbol');
            if (cycleBBSymbol === bbSymbol){
                singleRecord = record;
                return false;
            }
        });

        console.log('position I am evaluateing is ' + bbSymbol);
        console.log('market data found for  ' + singleRecord.get('BBSymbol'));
        console.log(singleRecord);

        //debugger;
        var lastPrice = singleRecord.get('Last_Price');
        var settle = singleRecord.get('Px_Settle');
        var qty = record.get('Quantity');
        var marketName = record.get('Description');
        var pnl = (lastPrice - settle) * qty;
        console.log(pnl);

        calculatedPositionsDataStore.add({
            BBSymbol: bbSymbol,
            Description: marketName,
            Quantity: qty,
            CalcPLSett: pnl
        });

        sayHello(singleRecord);

    }, this);



},

sayHello: function (singleRecord) {
    alert('hello');
    alert(singleRecord);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you're out of the scope of the ViewController.

In

```
positionsStore.each(function (record) { ...}
```

You are in the store scope, but the sayHello function is in the ViewController scope.

Assign the ViewController's scope to a variable, should solve your problem:

```
onClickCalculate: function () {
    console.log('calculation button was hit');

    var me = this; //NEW LINE

    var targetGrid = Ext.getCmp('positionsGridID');
    var positionsStore = targetGrid.store;
```

And then use it in the `positionsStore.each` function :

```
me.sayHello(singleRecord)
```

Comment: not sure if I am supposed to ask this here.. but my concept of store1/store2, to create a store3.  is that a good way to go about it, or is there a best practices that I am missing?